# How does imwarp handle complex numbers?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, complex-numbers

I have a complex image `I` (an nxm array of complex numbers).
I noticed that `imwarp` accepts complex images as input.

So this code:

```
J=imwarp(I, tform, 'linear');
```

will produce an output, that, on visual inspection seems to make sense.

But I could't find any information on how exactly the interpolation of the pixel values was done. Does anyone know about it or could point out documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interp` option uses the same mechanism as it is in regular `interp1`, `interp2`, ....etc.

With a complex image in **imwarp**, interpolation operates individually on the real and imaginary parts separately.